# how to convert Array<A> | Array<B> to Array<A | B> in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a type like the following:

```
type Schema = {
 name: string;
 status: "Active" | "Blocked";
}
```

And I have created the following Typescript Function:

```
type ConvertSchema<T> = {
 [key in keyof T]?: T[key] | T[key][];
}
```

I want to convert "Schema" type to "ConvertedSchemaCorrect" as following:

```
// This is exptected
type ConvertedSchemaCorrect = {
 name?: string | string[];
 status?: "Active" | "Blocked" | ("Active" | "Blocked")[]
}

// This is not expected (Typescript produces this)
type ConvertedSchemaInvalid = {
 name: string | string[]
 status: "Active" | "Blocked" | "Active"[] | "Blocked"[]
}
```

Comment: Works if you use `key in keyof T`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4CgoB2qyEAXFAM7ABOAlgQOYDc+VqwArheQEQCCcYLQBuEHlAA+UHgCEANgHs4AawgATHiwC+uUJCgBhBQVHVg8JGgA8AFQB8GPAG1VIKPSiuFAMyg2AugD85DYuECD+EqGu-k7+2ix60EYmEGbqFijoWCmm5ohZVplodixwxlRQqOS5acAZBWiYOITEZNIIPAA0lMDsXORO-IIiYl2yiirqPP5QWkA

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBPZgW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The question should be clear now... Please review...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
type ConvertSchema<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: T[key] | T[key][];
};

type ConvertedSchema = ConvertSchema<Schema>;

const x: ConvertedSchema = {
  name: ['foo', 'bar'],
  status: ['Active', 'Blocked']
}
```

NB it's `[key in keyof T]` not `[key in T]`. Your version doesn't compile at all for me (using TypeScript 4.4.3): I get "Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'."

Comment: An explanation of *why* it has to be `key in keyof T` would make a better answer. My comment already noted that change works.

Comment: There was a mistake while writing the question, please take a look at the question again. The answer that you gave doesn't work because I have already implemented this and it returns unexpected results. Please read the full question.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in comments, you're missing a `keyof` in the mapped type declaration: you have to give it a set of keys, not the object itself:

```js
type ConvertSchema<T> = {
 [key in keyof T]?: T[key] | T[key][];
}
```

That caused 3 TS errors, and probably that was what made the compiler misbehave (though I'm not quite sure how did it manage to give a type at all based on something it doesn't even understand).

---

You can also ensure that if one of the keys is an array, the other keys also have to be arrays (if that's what you want) by using something like this:

```js
type ConvertSchema<T> = T | {
 [key in keyof T]?: T[key][];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQN4CgoB2qyEAXFAM7ABOAlgQOYDc+VqwArheQEQCCcYLQBuEHlAA+UHgCEANgHs4AawgATHiwC+uUJCgBhBQVHVg8JGgA8AFQB8mKDck58AbVUgo9KJ4UAzJwBdAH5yGw8IECC3IO1cXXBoADkIAHcLFHQsIxMIM0zrQtQ7BLhjKigFACMAKwBGclSMxCzHPChCYjIoAHJUXoAafEpgdi5yXoEhUV7cHVwAekWASRNUOVo1ciISbwooVGpqVBBB0fGD2gOCBWAAOlxygkqa2oAmJvTi9pHdnrc-SGfWqvSCw06bE43D60xEEDmC2erzqAGYvi1LNlXJ1-uRAQNBr1QeCRlCJlBAXDZudevIlKo1GD5vggA)

Comment: I have edited the question, I missed that keyof keyword while writing the question!

Comment: But it does work with `keyof`!